# Can't login on Heroku deployed app, but can login locally

Tags: python, django

On my web-app, registering and signing in works great while am using the developing server http://127.0.0.1:8000/, But when I deployed the website on Heroku ,, it is not working well .. only users created using `createsuperuser` works ..

Also, after registering the user signs in automatically after registering.

But when they logout .. they can't login again

here are my code :

**signup view**

```
def signup(request):
    current_user_ip = get_client_ip(request)
    current_temp = Temp.objects.filter(created_by_ip=current_user_ip)
    current_temp.delete()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        signup_form = SignUpForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if signup_form.is_valid():
            signup_form.save()
            messages.info(request, "Thanks for registering. You are now logged in.")
            new_user = authenticate(username=signup_form.cleaned_data['email'],
                                    password=signup_form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                                    )
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        signup_form = SignUpForm()

    context = {
        'signup_form': signup_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EmailAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def clean_username(self):
        return self.cleaned_data["username"].lower()


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, help_text='Must be a valid E-mail')
    user_name = forms.CharField(required=True, help_text='')
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text='')
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text='Password confirmation')
    avatar = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'user_name', 'password1', 'password2', 'avatar')
        labels = {
            'user_name': 'user_name',
            'email': ' email',
            'password1': 'password1',
            'password2': 'password2',
            'avatar': 'avatar',
        }

    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        return data.lower()
```

**urls.py**

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(authentication_form=EmailAuthForm), name="login"),
path('signup/', web_site_views.signup, name='signup'),
```

Comment: `save` return user, you should check that to ensure that it's returning correctly.

Comment: Should I return user in the Auth function .. ?? I didn't get it. explain more please ( I am Still a Django beginner )

Comment: If you're using any semi-advanced IDE, you should be able to breakpoint your code to check values :)